# Network port number; why 16-bit has 65535, not 65536?

Tags: network

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking),

> A port number is a 16-bit unsigned integer, thus ranging from 0 to
>   65535

I assume 16-bit is equal to 2 power of 16 (please correct me if I'm wrong).

However, 2 power of 16 equal to 65536, not 65535.

May I know how the calculation is performed for this?

Comment: Hint: how many possible values are there when the lowest possible value is 0 and the highest possible value is 1?

Comment: @JanDvorak, 2 (0 and 1)?

Comment: Correct. Now, how many possible values are there when the lowest one is 0 and the highest one is 65535?

Comment: Ah, I got it. 65536 because the first value is 0, and last one is 65535.

Zero-based numbering or index origin = 0 is a way of numbering in which the initial element of a sequence is assigned the index 0, rather than the index 1 as is typical in everyday non-mathematical/non-programming circumstances. 

Under zero-based numbering, the initial element is sometimes termed the zeroth element, rather than the first element; zeroth is a coined ordinal number corresponding to the number zero.

Reference:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The port number is a representation of bit in base 2. 
2 power of 16 equal to 65536: It is the amount of numbers in base 2 that can be created with 16 bits, the number 65536 does not represent the last number that can be created in base 2 with 16 bits

In base 2, 
first number is 0000,0000,0000,0000 , in base 10 is 0 
second number is 0000,0000,0000,0001, in base 10 is 1 
third number is 0000,0000,0000,0010, in base 10 is 2 
fourth number is 0000,0000,0000,0011,  in base 10 is 3 
...
65536-th number is 1111,1111,1111,1111,  in base 10 is 65535

And therefore the last port is 65535 and not 65536